# iMac HDD transfer files to windows PC without affecting Mac OS x

Tags: hard-drive, imac

Hi I have iMac a very slow one and it's stops responding a lot and copying data takes ages so I want to transfer my data to a windows PC.

My question Is it possible to remove iMac hdd to transfer files without affecting OS X?!

I don't want to reinstall just put it back and clean it XD

Would it boot again after removal ?!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, removing the HD from a Mac to put it in a PC to transfer files would not work. Out of the box Windows PCs don't understand the disk format of the Mac. You can buy software that could make it possible but out of the box the answer is no.

Assuming you had that software simply copying the files off the Mac's HD would not hurt the drive as long as you are careful not to delete any necessary files from the Mac's HD.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out .do you have any suggestions or other way around this cause 1.5 t data would take an age on a slow and not responded imac

Comment: You may have to find another Mac, purchase some software that lets PCs read HFS+ disks or transfer it over a network cable between two computers. If you share the whole drive, connect directly to the PC and copy from the PC side a gigabit ethernet connection is faster than most USB.